# Is possible to back up files to two different hard disks at the same time?

Tags: hard-drive, backup

Is there any way using the luckyBackup application to backup the same directories and files to two different USB hard disks *in the same task*, instead of adding two different tasks? It will speed up a lot my backups.

Comment: No, but if you are comfortable at the command line you can likely pipe a command through tee to specify more than one target.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately there is no (direct*) way to use 2 different destination folders within the same task.
Each task will first calculate differences between **one** source & **one** destination and then proceed to data transfers accordingly.

* If your goal is to increase the backup disk redundancy, consider using some kind of disk raid.